# The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill' - visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

```
Dim stSQL As String
stSQL = "SELECT BookingID, Customer, Seat FROM tblBookings"

Dim stConString As String
stConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Online Movie Reservation System.accdb"

Dim conBookings As OleDbConnection
conBookings = New OleDbConnection
conBookings.ConnectionString = stConString
conBookings.Open()

Dim cmdSelectBookings As New OleDbCommand(stSQL, conBookings)

Dim dsBookings As New DataSet
Dim daBookings As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSelectBookings)

daBookings.Fill(dsBookings, "Bookings")
conBookings.Close()

MsgBox(dsBookings.Tables("Bookings").Rows.Count)
```

I want to use the code to fetch and view tables, which can be used offline for an online booking system. Using Visual Studio 2010

Thanks

Comment: Debug your code. Based on what you've posted there, I don't see how that error message is possible so I can only conclude that there's something that you're not telling us.  If you debug your code properly, you'll be able to see the values of every property as the code executes, so you'll be able to see if, when and with what that `SelectCommand` is set.

Comment: By the way, your code is way more convoluted than is required. You only need two lines of code. The data adapter constructor will take a query string and a connection string as arguments and the call to `Fill` will automatically open and close the connection, so that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks ... Working on that now